# Was the ISRO Mars mission really scaled down?

Tags: mars, isro, pslv, mars-orbiter-mission

This [news-report](http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/india-scales-down-mars-mission/article4279757.ece) writes to say

> India’s bid to explore Mars will be a scaled down affair with the space agency flying experimental payload of less than 15 kg as against 25kg planned originally

- Was the Mars mission really scaled down?

  - Why?
- What instruments in the original payload did *not* make it to the scaled down mission?

Comment: I think this was decided long time ago and might have something to do with the [cryogenic upper stage of ISRO's GSLV](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/1162/49) that they had problems with, so they opted for [PSLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle) that doesn't have such lifting capacity.

Answer (score 3):

Originally, MOM was going to [use the GSLV](http://isp.justthe80.com/planetary-exploration/mars-obiter) to launch. The [GSLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle) has about 50% more capacity than the [PSLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle). As a result, a few things had to be cut back from the mission, including the payload, removal of a direct to Mars orbit, among others.

Comment: This answers *most* of the question, but is a bit lacking in the second category - which instruments didn't make it?

Comment: +1 for the note on capacity change because of the vehicle. Ditto to @Undo's remark on payload content though )+:

Comment: I just can't find any information on it. Sigh. Maybe later...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I don't think you'll find it because the 2006 proposed GSLV mission was [planned to have ~ 25 kg scientific payload on a ~ 500 kg orbiter](http://m.indianexpress.com/news/indias-mars-mission-the-countdown-begins-for-isros-voyage-to-the-red-planet/1178892/) but the scientific instruments were not yet selected, so it would merely be a list of all kinds of possible ones, some talked of perhaps 11-12 of them. The PSLV MOM mission with an under 15 kg scientific payload was approved and funded much later in 2012 after GSLV dual failures of its cryo upper stage in 2010.